# Creating superclass table to reduce relationship amount

Tags: relational-database, entity-relationship

Since relational databases does not support direct inheritance and foreing keys can only refer one table , I had to improvize a solution(which i don't think unique or whatever) .

In my relational database there are entityA,entityB1 and entityB2 entities.entityB1 and entityB2 represents similar real life objects ,but have different attribute numbers,like sports cars and family cars.Let's say entityA can create "BUYS" relationship with both entity.Normally it can be done with 2 seperate relationships , which have foreign keys to 2 seperate tables.

Here is my solution,I created entity B , that has attribute B_ID only.When there is a record inserted to entityB1 or entityB2,record's primary key inserted entityB as B_ID as well.This way I try to aim indirectly referring entityB1 and entityB2 with a single relationship.

Can you suggest me better way,since I will need to use extra join to access entityB1 and entityB2's attributes this way?

Answer (score 0):

This is a common misconception regarding super-types / sub-types.

The super-typing should always be included in a logical model.  If the performance requirements of the particular application cannot be met, this can be addressed collapsing the super-type into the various sub-types in the physical model for the application.  Care should be taken to insure that there is no duplication of prime keys in sub-type table and that the collapsed non-key attributes in the physical model correctly adhere to those rules specified in the logical model.

Care should also be taken to verify that there is performance issue (via load testing for example). Collapsing super-types into sub-types can be problematic when it comes to sharing data between multiple applications / systems / enterprises.

Another physical modeling approach is to coalesce the sub-types into the super-types. This is achieved by defining all of the sub-type attributes as physical only columns into the super-type table. Care should be taken to ensure that the columns for the distinct sub-type are the only ones filled in and that the columns for the other subs-types remain null.

Hope this helps.